# How to end if statement in java?

Tags: java

I am a beginner to java and I am working on a problem for a converter between Fahrenheit and Celsius. However, if someone selects the first option, when that code runs, the second option automatically runs as shown below. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FahrenheittoCelsius {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("If you would like to convert a temperature from Fahrenheit to Celcius, enter 1.");
        System.out.println("If you would like to convert a temperature from Celcius to Fahrenheit, enter 2.");
        int mode = scan.nextInt();
        if (mode == 1);
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit");
            int Ftemp = scan.nextInt();
            int Cnewtemp = (Ftemp - 32) * 5 / 9;
            System.out.println("The temperature in Celcius is " + Cnewtemp + " degrees.");
        }
        if (mode == 2);
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the temperature in Celcius");
            int Ctemp = scan.nextInt();
            int Fnewtemp = Ctemp * 9 / 5 + 32;
            System.out.println("The temperature in Fahrenheit is " + Fnewtemp + " degrees.");   
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with semicolons is very common. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolons after the if statements. You are ending them before they actually begin, and so, all of the code runs.

In Java, the brackets should follow immediately after the closing parenthesis. (The line after also counts as directly after)

The code should look like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FahrenheittoCelsius {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("If you would like to convert a temperature from Fahrenheit to Celcius, enter 1.");
      System.out.println("If you would like to convert a temperature from Celcius to Fahrenheit, enter 2.");
      int mode = scan.nextInt();
      if (mode == 1)
      {   
          System.out.println("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit");
          int Ftemp = scan.nextInt();
          int Cnewtemp = (Ftemp - 32) * 5 / 9;
          System.out.println("The temperature in Celcius is " + Cnewtemp + " degrees.");
       }
      if (mode == 2)
      {   
          System.out.println("Enter the temperature in Celcius");
          int Ctemp = scan.nextInt();
          int Fnewtemp = Ctemp * 9 / 5 + 32;
          System.out.println("The temperature in Fahrenheit is " + Fnewtemp + " degrees.");   
      }       
  }

}
```

Comment: To add a bit more clarity to the answer, can you perhaps include what the code should look like?

Answer (score -1):

change the if statements to:

```
public class FahrenheittoCelsius {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("If you would like to convert a temperature from Fahrenheit to Celcius, enter 1.");
        System.out.println("If you would like to convert a temperature from Celcius to Fahrenheit, enter 2.");
        int mode = scan.nextInt();
        if (mode == 1)
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit");
            int Ftemp = scan.nextInt();
            int Cnewtemp = (Ftemp - 32) * 5 / 9;
            System.out.println("The temperature in Celcius is " + Cnewtemp + " degrees.");
        }
        else if (mode == 2)
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the temperature in Celcius");
            int Ctemp = scan.nextInt();
            int Fnewtemp = Ctemp * 9 / 5 + 32;
            System.out.println("The temperature in Fahrenheit is " + Fnewtemp + " degrees.");   
        }       
    }

}
```